# ServiceNow Group Approval, not firing

Tags: servicenow

I have a group approval in a workflow it fires some times and does not fire at other times. The problem is only found in the production environment and cannot be created in Sandbox or Dev. The stage of the workflow of the approval is Stage:running, all the logs show nothing incorrect. but the users do not receive an approval.

Comment: Are the group approval records not getting created? Or is it that the group approval records are there, but users aren't getting notified of them?

Comment: when you go into the RITM to view the request there is just no names listed from the group that is approving, it works perfect in the other environments and do actually work at times in production, it seems to work correctly one moment then not the next.

Comment: Is it always the same group approving. Or does one group work in prod but another always fails?

Comment: Does the group have the same sys_id in production as in the test environment?
(In other words, how do you ensure that?)